# How can I download my uploaded file on Bonita using a Link

Tags: file-upload, bonita

I have created my submission form in Bonita and I have added all my variables. Here below is a photo of my submission form

[image]

Here is the Validation Form

[image]

I want to be able to get the file uploaded on the first form, to the validation form, so I can be able to download it as a link.

But when I tried to reference it, I get an error message when I tried to click on the link

[image]
[image]

How can I reference the file correctly? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Note: You would need to press the ***fx*** button in the URL field and provide the input like `'/bonita/portal/' + context.file_ref.url`

Also there are couple of cases to check in your question:

1. If you are saving the input file to a process "Document", then you can fetch as `'/bonita/portal/' + context.file_ref.url` 
   where 
   *file* is the name of the process document.
2. I understand from your first image that you have the file is child inside a complex contract input. But as you cannot save a file inside a business object, you can instead save the document URL in the process and while loading, you can simply use 
   `'/bonita/portal/' + context.submit_ref.File` 
   where *submit* is the name of the business variable and *File* is the attribute where you saved the document URL